# Can either of the following Unforeseeable Events allow me to avoid capital tax on a sale of an apartment abroad?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, house-sale

I used to live in my apartment which is located outside the U.S. I have been renting it out for 5.5 years. I saw on the [website](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2016_publink10009003) of the IRS that if there were Unforeseeable Events then one can avoid paying tax on the sale. I file jointly so that means avoiding paying tax on on $500k of profit.

I have 2 Unforeseeable Events that apply to me,

1. the apartment is very small, since I bought it in 2003, over the years we became a family of 9 people. There was no way to know this when I bought it. We moved out to a larger place. Would the fact that it's to small to live in it for a family of our size qualify to avoid the tax on 500k?
2. In about 6 months, the entire building will be razed. A private company is doing this in exchange to rebuild the building with an additional 25 apartments which they have the rights to sell. There is no cost to the present apartment owners but we all signed on it and can not back out. (I know that this sounds like a great thing but it's been going on for 5+ years so some feel that it simple took too long for this great thing to happen. The ETA to move back in is another 5-7 years. In the meanwhile everyone must go live somewhere else.)

So it's not an option to go live there for another 2 years, the building won't exist shortly.

If I'd want to sell now, could I use #1 or #2 to avoid paying capital tax on the 500k as I would have had if I lived there 2 more years? If this is a yes, how to properly prove it to the IRS. How to fill out 1040 for the year 2022 with this sale in it?

Comment: Are you living in it right now, or is it a rental? The $500k exclusion is for primary residence of a married couple, it doesn't sound like this applies to you from your question.

Comment: I am not living in it. It's being rented which I report the income. But soon everyone must vacate the building and eventually it will be demolished. Can I somehow get an exclusion? If I have the renter leave, would that help? Any way I can do this? My goal is to be able to buy a place where I wish to live and that we can fit in it comfortably. But I would continue to live outside the U.S..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $500K exclusion you're talking about is a "principal residence" exclusion ([IRC Sec. 121](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/121)). Since your property is a rental, it is not covered by that section. I doubt you'd be able to satisfy the exceptions requirements by evicting the tenant and moving there yourself given that you already knew about the imminent buy-out for awhile now.

What you can potentially do is a [Sec. 1031 exchange](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/like-kind-exchanges-real-estate-tax-tips), with which you can defer the tax and move the proceeds into a new rental instead of the old one (you can exchange one foreign property for another, but not a foreign property for a US property). Sec. 1031 has very strict requirements on the timeline of the exchange and the process. The new property must also be a rental (at least for a while, usually at least for a couple of years for the IRS to accept it as a "like kind" exchange).